# SSM with Shiro, filter ineffective, just display only when you login then you can see the page, why it happens?

Tags: java, shiro, ssm

After the project starts, it displayed only after  success login ,then you can see the page, when I debug, found SecurityFilter not excute, UserRealm doGetAuthorizationInfo () method is not excute. where is the  problem? Grateful! .

Can anyone help me work out why this did execute?

It's my class:

```
public class UserRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {


    @Resource
    private UserService userService;

    /**
     * @param principalCollection
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principalCollection) {
        String username=principalCollection.getPrimaryPrincipal().toString();
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info=new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        Set<String> roleName=userService.findRoles(username);
        Set<String> permissions=userService.findPermissions(username);
        info.setRoles(roleName);
        info.setStringPermissions(permissions);
        return info;
    }

    /**
     * @param token
     * @return
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     */
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

        String username=token.getPrincipal().toString();
        User user=userService.findUserByUsername(username);
        if(user!=null){

            AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),user.getUsername()) ;
            return authenticationInfo;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

filter:

public class SecurityFilter extends AccessControlFilter {

```
@Override
protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request,
                                  ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws Exception {


    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String url = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

    if (null != token || isLoginRequest(request, response)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request,
                                 ServletResponse response) throws Exception {


    saveRequestAndRedirectToLogin(request, response);
    return false ;
}
```

}

realm:

public class UserRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

@Resource

private UserService userService;

/**  *

- @param principalCollection

  - @return  */

  @Override

protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principalCollection) {

String username=principalCollection.getPrimaryPrincipal().toString();

SimpleAuthorizationInfo info=new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();

Set roleName=userService.findRoles(username);

Set permissions=userService.findPermissions(username);

info.setRoles(roleName);

info.setStringPermissions(permissions);

return info;

}

/**  *

- @param token

  - @return
- @throws AuthenticationException

  */

@Override

protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

String username=token.getPrincipal().toString();

User user=userService.findUserByUsername(username);

if(user!=null){

AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),user.getUsername()) ;

return authenticationInfo;  }else {

return null;

}

}

}

Comment: Sounds like the user did not authenticate.  Authentication will happen before authorization.  This question is a bit vague though, you will need to provide more information.

Comment: doGetAuthenticationInfo() method excuted,then it  didn't executed the method doGetAuthorizationInfo().I don't know why...@Brian Demers